# No Valid GPG found while installing kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, package, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

Error while adding kubernetes key

```
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

I tried using `wget` verbose command

```
wget --no-check-certificate -vO - https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
--2018-10-05 09:55:13--  https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
Resolving packages.cloud.google.com (packages.cloud.google.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘packages.cloud.google.com’
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

How can I get past that error in my Kubernetes installation step?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check first if you should be using a proxy to access external URLs (you would then have to declare that proxy in a `.wgetrc`)

But see also if using `curl -4 -s...` (forcing IPV4 instead of a possible default IPV6) would work better, as described in "[Ubuntu 16.04: curl, wget, ssh could not resolve host from dnsmasq with IPv6](https://wyldeplayground.net/ubuntu-16-04-curl-wget-ssh-could-not-resolve-host-from-dnsmasq-with-ipv6/)".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

Not sure what is the exact issue but below below solution helped me resolve this issue

cat /etc/resolv.conf # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

**as this file was lacking nameservers. Adding nameservers resolved the issue**